# pyinstaller error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__builtin__'

Tags: python, compiler-errors, pyinstaller, exe, speed-test

I'm making a desktop application in python, in which I use the `speedtest-cli` library.
I decided to build my project in exe format using `pyinstaller` (I use the `GUI version - auto-py-to-exe`).
When I build the project in `exe` and open `main.py`, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "speedtest.py", line 156, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__builtin__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "speedtest_thread.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "speedtest.py", line 179, in <module>
  File "speedtest.py", line 166, in __init__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

Here's a screenshot of my problem:
[image: Error pyinstaller speedtest-cli]

I know the problem has been dealt with before, here is a link to a similar discussion:
[Pyinstaller speedtest convert to exe error; no module name "__builtin__"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69321087/pyinstaller-speedtest-convert-to-exe-error-no-module-name-builtin?newreg=2cb4c3d09b0c4856943c2fe19b218ade)

but I understood it was not solved, maybe something has changed now?

I tried changing `__builtin__` to `builtins`, but still it didn't help.

If it helps I'm using `python 3.12.1`.

Comment: *"I tried changing `__builtin__` to `builtins`, but still it didn't help."* Where? Why did you think it will help? Show us *your* code. Also, any chance you created a file called `speedtest.py` in your project?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DeepSpace 

In this discussion at stackoverflow.com/questions/69321087/…. said to replace `C:\Users\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3\Lib\site-packages\speedtest.py`. all lines with `__builtin__` to `builtins`, which is what I did. My project uses the `speedtest-cli` library

Comment: Here's a snippet of code that uses this library:
``speedtester = speedtest.Speedtest()
speedtester.get_best_server() 
download_speed = speedtester.download()
upload_speed = speedtester.upload()
``